# Is it stylistically better to say « je reviens » instead of « je viens de revenir »?

Tags: choix-de-mot

> Je **reviens** de la boulangerie sur Main Street.
>
> {vs}: Je **viens de revenir** de la boulangerie sur Main Street.

In order to express the idea of « je viens tout juste de revenir », the speaker said « je reviens ». I wonder if the speaker tried to avoid the *duality* of « venir » and « revenir »?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Je viens de revenir* is acceptable but looks like a repetition. *Je reviens* is indeed better. If you want to insist about the fact it just happened, you can use:

> Je reviens juste de la boulangerie sur Main Street.

Comment: Hi. I take it, then, that « venir » and « revenir » are rare instances where the present tense can refer to an immediate past.

Answer (score 1):

In *Je **viens** de re**venir** de la boulangerie sur Main Street*, there is a repetition of *venir* which is not very elegant. So I would prefer to use *Je reviens de la boulangerie sur Main Street*.

If you don't want to use *présent de l'indicatif*, you may use *passé composé*:

> Je suis revenu de la boulangerie (à l'instant)